# spyder IDE windows

Tags: console, ide, spyder

I closed some windows on Spyder IDE yesterday. I wish to open them back but I am not able to. Trying since yesterday but to no avail. Please tell me how to do it. I wish to go from 1st to 2nd. Notice I want the console window and variable&File explorers

[image: This is my spyder IDE]

[image: This is my target Spyder IDE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Spyder panes are available in the menu

`View > Panes`

The ones you want are called *Variable Explorer* and *IPython console*.